# Save entities in Spring Data JPA which contains a list of another entity type

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Guys I'm new to Spring so bear with me.
I have two entities. User and Genre.
User entity contains a list of Genre entities. i.e. "User has genres"
("Genre has users" is not a requirement of me.)

My two entities...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String userEmail;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String imgUrl;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genres_id"))
    private List<Genre> genres;
  
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class Genre {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;


}
```

and this is the request body I'm sending to save my User record...

```
{
   "username":"test username",
   "userEmail":"test@gmail.com",
   "firstName":"test fname",
   "lastName":"test lname",
   "imgUrl":"url",
   "genres":[
      {
         "id":8,
         "name":"Drama"
      }
   ]
}
```

I maintain a table of genres. When I want to save a user, I pick some genres from the table, save them in a list in User entity and send them to save(). My expectation is to save those relationships in user_genres table with user_id and genre_id.

**My problem is, when I try to save a user with a genre object, if there is already a user with a genre object of id as same as in the user I'm trying to save, it gives me an exception saying that id of genre already exists.**

i.e. Suppose I already have a user which contains a genre of id 8. Now I'm sending a new user, that means with a new user_id, which also contains a genre with id 8. Then it will give me an exception,

> SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '8' for key 'UK_1ro2jvu91tg2xsrdye9sk9j1q'

This works fine if I use a different genre with a different id. Please tell me a way to obtain the result as I expected. Thanks.

My repository,

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {}
```

My service,

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity save(User user) {
        if (getUserByUserEmail(user.getUserEmail()) == null)
            return new ResponseEntity(userRepository.save(user), HttpStatus.OK);
        return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    public User getUserByUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        return userRepository.findByUserEmail(userEmail);
    }
}
```

My controller,

```
@Autowired
    UserServiceImpl userService;


    @PostMapping("/users")
    public ResponseEntity save(@RequestBody User user) {

        return userService.save(user);
    }
```

**Update :**
Cascade type changed to MERGE
In User,

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
 @JoinTable(name = "user_genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id"), 
 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genres_id"))
    private List<Genre> genres;
```

**Update :** Overrided following methods inside User and Genre

In User,

```
@Override

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), user.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    
}
```

In Genre,

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Genre)) return false;
        Genre genre = (Genre) o;
        return Objects.equals(getId(), genre.getId());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId());
    }
```

Comment: SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '8' for key 'UK_1ro2jvu91tg2xsrdye9sk9j1q'  To me this error means that there is already a user_id with value UK_1ro2jvu91tg2xsrdye9sk9j1q  in user_genres..

Can you show the payload of the User you are passing into your REST endpoint?  I think you might be using the same user_id.  Just a thought

Comment: @SusanMustafa Thanks for the comment. I have posted the payload I'm sending to save the User in the question details. Actually the user id is Integer and it is auto generated. So "UK_1ro2jvu91tg2xsrdye9sk9j1q" cannot be the user id. "Duplicate entry '8' " is coming from the Genre object that I have passed in the User entity. 
And also I am expecting to have multiple records with the same user_id in the user_genres table. Because I'm mapping Multiple users to multiple Genres.

Comment: are you doing any CREATE TABLE yourself?  or everything done through JPA?  The reason I ask, is because your constraint might be wrong.  The column genre_id might be set as the UNIQUE constraint instead of a combination of both (User_ID and genre_ID)

Comment: Table was created by JPA. 
But after reading your comment I just realized that even though I did the changes suggested by Boug, I didn't drop my previous schema!! Now I dropped my schema and restarted the service. Now it's working fine! Thank you @SusanMustafa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1**

Create `hashcode()` and `equals()` methods for both User and Genre based on their Id fields.

**Step 2**

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
 @JoinTable(name = "user_genres", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "User_id"), 
 inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genres_id"))
    private List<Genre> genres;
```

Now you should be ready to go.

Comment: Hey thanks for the response.
I did the above two steps.
In user i overrided equals and hashcode methods. see the update.

And I added the Merge cascade type. But still I get the same exception

Comment: and i did the same for Genre

Comment: You must use the override also for Genre based on it's Id

Comment: yes i did. i will add that also to the update

Comment: try once with cascade=CascadeType.ALL

Comment: If that does not work out please post the code with which you make the saving so that we can find what goes wrong

Comment: When I changed cascade=CascadeType.ALL , I got `PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:`
I will update the code with saving function

Comment: I dropped the whole schema and restarted my service and it worked. Thank you!